# jQuery animation: ignore styling with css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I am doing animation with jQuery (like `$(".myClass").slideDown()`) it adds some styles inline to my object:

```
# Before:
<div class='myItem'>...</div>
# Animation:
=> $(".myItem").slideDown();
# After:
<div class='myItem' style='display: block'>
```

**Question is how to return my object to original state after animation.**

I've got two approaches:

- I can use cool `wrap()` function to wrap my object, animate it and `unwrap()` as callback for animation.
- I can save my original state `html = $(".myItem").html()` and assign it back after animation.

Why I need it? Actually I was digging in one web site, that was using ancient (but quite cool) [CSS dropdown menu](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/dd_valid.html). My goal is to add animation for dropdown (slideDown) with jQuery. Problem is that my animation breaks css styling and it stops working. Now I am using my first approach with `wrap`, but it don't work in IE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you not just remove the style attribute once the animation has completed, i.e., within the callback?

```
$(".myItem").slideDown("slow", function() {
    $(this).removeAttr("style");
});
```